# How to locate a link in protractor

Tags: protractor

I am trying to locate a link which after clicking a pop up panel would show up for logging in. But it seems I can't get to the link. I have tried different methods like xpath, findElement, locating by css or class name or .. but nothing has worked. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide relevant reproducible your configuration, also a sample test where this doesn't work. Also provide the rendered HTML of the page that is in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default you can also locate a link with one of the following lines:

`element(by.linkText('TEXT OF THE LINK'))...`

`element(by.partialLinkText('PARTIAL TEXT OF THE LINK'))...`

`element(by.tagName('a'))...`

See [here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy) for a more detailed information about the different locators.

**Complement:**

If the link only appears if you click on your pop up panel, then you need to wait until your link becomes visible and clickable.

In that case, you can wait for your element to become visible with following:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var isClickable = EC.elementToBeClickable(element(by.partialLinkText('Sign up')));

browser.wait(isClickable, 5000); //Waits 5 seconds for your element to become visible and clickable, otherwise a timeout exception will be thrown

element(by.partialLinkText('Sign up')).click(); // Or do something else with your element
```

Comment: I already tried it but I got the error which says "No element found using by(partualLinkText..."

Comment: Okay, please provide your used code and the respektive parts of the DOM, so we can find a solution

Comment: <li class="primary-item ng-scope" ng-if="!header.user.AUTHORIZED_USER" href="javascript:;"><a ng-click="header.userService.openLoginWindow();" href="">Sign up / Log in</a></li>  ......and in my code I just simply trying to get to the link by element(by.partialLinkText('Sign up'))

Comment: Okay, i've edited my answer. I hope that will solve your problem ;-)

Comment: Thank you @Batajus , that was helpful

Comment: No problem ;-) 
If my answer was correct, I would appreciate it, if you would accept my answer ;-)